# Overriding devise registration controller for redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Devise functionality needs to be customized and the the `RegistrationsController` is created.
However, the default set-up for the create action is

```
super do |resource|

end
```

which in itself is a bit of a black box, as it goes to the superclass.  It obvious is wired up for redirection.  Thus:

```
super do |resource|
  [...]
  if @user.save?
    redirect_to some_user_attribute_path
  else
    redirect_to a_parameter_based_path
  end
end
```

is not possible as it will naturally create a

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in Users::RegistrationsController#create
```

Devise wikis only deal with successful actions or all-encompassing approaches.

It is a goal to avoid ApplicationController methods, as this use-case has very specific behaviours for only user creation according success or failure (in practice the return is to the same page, but in the case of the failure, is defined via a `params[:company][:id]` value in lieu of `@user.company_id`

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should override the method completely since you don't want the [redirection handling](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/1bb5fcbbecfb9452e194341e030fdc1d364f6ee4/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L21) that is after the `yield`. So, you could do this:

```rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save?
      redirect_to some_user_attribute_path
    else
      redirect_to a_parameter_based_path
    end
  end
end
```

Note: If you need to sign up the user or any other stuff that devise does, you should copy it from the original method